# How to report the standard error of a percentage?

Tags: standard-error, communication

I have a variable that is a proportion. Let's say it is the proportion of boys in a classroom. I calculate its standard error as well. Suppose the value and its standard error is $0.1512$, and $0.0341$. I made these numbers up.

In a paper, I would just write

$$
0.1512 \\
(0.0341)
$$

I would like to display these numbers in a table as percentage so that the non-technical reader can easily understand the number. How should I report the standard error? One option is to just omit it, since the non-technical reader would not care about it. But please assume I need to report it as well. Is it like:

$$
15.12\% \\
(3.41\%)
$$

Or:

$$
15.12\% \\
(0.0341)
$$

Both seem awkward to me. The first one is weird because standard errors are not supposed to have a metric? But the second one is also awkward because $0.0341$ is the standard error of $0.1512$! Is there no good way to do this?

Comment: "because standard errors are not supposed to have a metric" - incorrect. their unit of measure matches the variable's

Comment: 15.12%(3.41%) is almost correct. But it should be 15.12% (3.41pp), where pp is percentage points. otherwise it implies a multiplicative standard error

Comment: @Alex J thanks! that makes sense!